# How to extract <td> elements with no attributes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I am a newbie in web scraping and I have been stuck with some issue. I tried and searched but nothing at all. I want to extract data from the table. The problem is that tr and td elements don't have attributes, just class. `<td class="review-value">` is the same for different values. I don't know how to separate them. I need lists with every single value for example:

```py
list_1 = [aircraft1, aircraft2, aircraft3, ..]
list_2 = [type_of_traveller1, type_of_traveller2, ...]
list_3 = [cabin_flown1, cabin_flown2,...]
list_4 = [route1, route2,...]
list_5 = [date_flown1, date_flown2, ..]
```

This is the table code:

```html
<table class="review-ratings">
  <tr>
    <td class="review-rating-header aircraft">Aircraft</td>
    <td class="review-value">Boeing 787-9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="review-rating-header type_of_traveller">Type Of Traveller</td>
    <td class="review-value">Couple Leisure</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="review-rating-header cabin_flown">Seat Type</td>
    <td class="review-value">Business Class</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="review-rating-header route">Route</td>
    <td class="review-value">Mexico City to London</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="review-rating-header date_flown">Date Flown</td>
    <td class="review-value">February 2023</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using BeautifulSoup:

```py
page = requests.get(url)
table = soup.find('article')
review_table = table.find_all('table', class_ = 'review-  ratings')
find_tr_header = table.find_all('td', class_ = 'review-rating-header')
headers = []
for i in find_tr_header:
     headers.append(i.text.strip())
```

And I don't know what to do with class="review-value".

Comment: Have a look at the [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in your table each field has a cell `.review-value` that is following it (direct sibling).

So what you can do is use the selector **+** in CSS.
For instance `.aircraft + .review-value` will give you the value of the aircraft.

In Beautiful Soup you can even avoid this type of selector since there are built-in methods available for you. Check [next-sibling](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling)